# Extended With-keyword in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, with-statement

In my current project everyone names variables and methods after what they are and what they do. This is good for quickly understanding the code, but with a lot of long varible names comes some headaches, such as when copying a dataset to an entity/object. So, while you understand the code, the readability still takes a blow.

```
veryLongVariableName.Id = datasetVeryLongVariableName.Id
veryLongVariablename.Something = datasetVeryLongVariableName.Something
etc.
```

Using VB.NET's With keyword can help.

```
With veryLongVariableName

    .Id = datasetVeryLongVariableName.Id
    .Something = datasetVeryLongVariableName.Something

End With
```

Now, my question, is there any way of using With, or something similar, but for several variables at the same time? Something like:

```
With veryLongVariableName As a, datasetVeryLongVariableName as b

    a.Id = b.Id
    a.Something = b.Something

End With
```

I'm all for descriptive naming conventions, but they do tend to clutter things. Especially in VB!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the code that does these sets of assignments is part of a single logical action then you could refactor it out into it's own method/function call.  While this doesn't specifically answer your question about a multiple with usage, it would improve readibility in lines with suggestions found in popular books such as Code Complete.

Comment: While it doesn't do exactly what I want, this is a good answer. I'm not a fan of too far gone refactoring, though. I sometimes find it takes the code out of context, and makes it harder to read (and wears the F12 button out ;) ) when you have to jump from method to method to find the actual operation.

Comment: +1 on your comment.  I definitely agree that it will make debugging more tedious.  The idea is that it will make your functions/methods easier to test and understand.  From everything I have read proper encapsulation is one of the best methods to combat code complexity.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible.

`With` works with a single object only. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx).

You can however, [nest `With` statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172864.aspx) (though this is not recommended as you could end up making your code really unreadable).

Comment: +1 Didn't know you could nest them.  Glad you put a warning on it.

Comment: Nesting, you say. Interesting, but looks like it could lead to all sorts of readability issues.

Answer (score 2):

Behind the scenes, all the `With` keyword does is declare a temporary variable that references the object you specify. Its references will be compiled to exactly the same IL code as fully-qualifying the object name, so there is no performance penalty. You can easily do this yourself:

```
Dim a as MyClass = veryLongVariableName
Dim b as MyOtherClass = datasetVeryLongVariableName

a.Id = b.Id
a.Something = b.Something
```

Comment: Indeed. However, what I like about With is that it has a beginning and end, and a clear use. Declaring new variables might confuse someone else reading the code, so in the end, the level of readability stays about the same with this solution. Good answer though.